# Exclude count of annotate items in Django Query

Tags: python, django

I am querying the DB to get a list of objects, and using annotate() to count how many associated Items they have with it.

I'd like to only return objects with an associated `item` count above 5.

```
lists = List.objects.exclude(picture_url='').exclude(picture_url__icontains='google').select_related('city','city__country', 'user', 'user__profile').annotate(items_added=Count('item'))[:10]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lists = List.objects.exclude(picture_url='') \
        .exclude(picture_url__icontains='google') \
        .select_related('city','city__country', 'user', 'user__profile') \
        .annotate(items_added=Count('item')) \
        .filter(items_added__gt=5)[:10]
```

> Unlike aggregate(), annotate() is not a terminal clause. The output of
>   the annotate() clause is a QuerySet; this QuerySet can be modified
>   using any other QuerySet operation, including filter(), order_by, or
>   even additional calls to annotate().

Comment: Actually my connection stalled :)